# Ubuntu 22 stuck in login loop after installation. xauthority file seems missing

Tags: 22.04, login

I tried installing ubuntu 22 LTS on my lenovo ideapad, but after installation the system is stuck in a login loop. I used ctrl+alt+F3 to login via terminal and saw that xAuthority file is missing.

Can someone please help in solving this? Thanks

Comment: Linux is case sensitive and the file should be `~/.Xauthority` instead of `~/xAuthority` or `~/.xAuthority`

Comment: Also, did you install the regular default Ubuntu desktop? And have you tried any other solutions like running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: The xauthority missing while you're trying to fix things is fine. In fact, one way to fix these kinds of login loops is to delete that file and all capitalization and punctuation variants of it.